# Parsename,CharIndex, or a Substring?

Tags: sql-server-2008

So here is the dilemma I am faced with, I have roughly 50 thousand records that each have a Plaintiff & Defendant name, both of these names reside within one column, I would like to parse them out into two separate columns. The names vary in length, as names do, and some of them have a Prefix or a Suffix. Prefixes and Suffixes aside, this shouldn't be a difficult query to write, but where I am getting hung up is in the middle of the string. 
The data I am working with is in the following format:

```
Column_Name
John Doe V Elton John
Jane Doe V Elton John
David Smith V Elton John
```

I have tried to write a query that separates the names around the 'V' in hopes that my target data will ultimately look like this:

Plaintiff_Name|Defendant_Name|
John Doe      |Elton John    |

However, when I tell it to replace a 'v' with a ' ' it replaces every V within the string with a space. Any suggestions you guys have to offer, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

**Nathaniel Block**

Comment: Is all of this sample data in `Column_Name` for one row?  `John Doe V Elton John Jane Doe V Elton John David Smith V Elton John`

Comment: No sir, there are multiple rows. I.E. John Doe V Elton John are the plaintiffs and defendants for the first row. The second row has different set of Plaintiff/Defendant names, like Jane Doe V Elton John.

Comment: You say that some names have suffixes. Is it possible to have a suffix of "V" meaning "the 5th"? If so, it will be tricky to do a simple split on the " V ", especially if the name of the left has the "V" in which case the name is "John Doe, V V Elton John"

Comment: I edited the question to put the column name and 3 rows into a Code Sample format.

Comment: srutzky, Thankfully there are no suffixes of 'V'. Most of the Suffixes are just 'the 1rst' or 'the 2nd'

Comment: Ok, then there is a fairly easy solution. Gimme a minute to post it.

Comment: Roger that, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would start with rows that have exactly one occurrence of ` V `.  Convert those first, and flag the rows that are converted.  Then move on to the unconverted rows.  Depending on how many there are, and how much variance there is, you could convert them manually, or write an new UPDATE statement with appropriate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it has been stated in a comment on the original question that no names will ever have a "V" suffix, you can use CHARINDEX to find the position of " V " (i.e. space-V-space) and then use SUBSTRING to get both parts:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  tmp.COLUMN_NAME,
            tmp.OTHER_FIELD,
            CHARINDEX(' V ', tmp.COLUMN_NAME) AS [DelimiterPosition]
    FROM (
            SELECT 'John Doe V Elton John', 23
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Jane Doe V Elton John', 78922
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'David Smith V Elton John', 932
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'David Doe 5th v Elton John', 53
        ) AS tmp(COLUMN_NAME, OTHER_FIELD)
)
SELECT  cte.COLUMN_NAME,
    SUBSTRING(cte.COLUMN_NAME, 1, (cte.DelimiterPosition - 1)) AS [Plaintiff],
    SUBSTRING(cte.COLUMN_NAME, (cte.DelimiterPosition + 3), 500) AS [Defendant],
        cte.OTHER_FIELD
FROM cte
```

Output:

```
COLUMN_NAME                 Plaintiff      Defendant    OTHER_FIELD
John Doe V Elton John       John Doe       Elton John   23
Jane Doe V Elton John       Jane Doe       Elton John   78922
David Smith V Elton John    David Smith    Elton John   932
David Doe 5th v Elton John  David Doe 5th  Elton John   53
```

Comment: Sheer paranoia: This will catch the first instance of ` V ` in the string. A second scan could be made for additional ` V ` instances in the Defendant column, to be sure there weren't any.

Comment: srutzky, as you already know, this works! Thanks so much for your help today. Jayvee, DMason, thanks for commenting, I am going to be able to get this data cleaned up and split into the columns I need it split into now. I couldn't have done it without y'all

Comment: @user3495301: yer welcome. Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace ' v ' including spaces to protect the 'v' within the strings, you might lose a middle initial if it hasn't got a dot or a 5th suffix though.